# Possible to using SQL query to get last 30 minutes created account from Magento?

Tags: database, customer-account

Possible using SQL query to get last 30 minutes created customer account from Magento? I want to run a cron job that it can get the last 30 minutes created customer account id. so base on ID, I can use Magento object manager to get last name, first name ...etc

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from customer_entity where created_at >=  (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
```